# Got following error when try to execute first script to open web url with help of gecko driver -

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code is as below:

```
package nw;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test {




        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

             driver.get("http://www.shop.demoqa.com");
}
}
```

Hello i am facing this issue in selenium while launching the above given program --

program..plz help me

> ```
> com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<clinit>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>
> at nw.test.main(test.java:14)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
> com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
>
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ```

Comment: share your code .. without seen that no one can observe the issue

Comment: package nw;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test {
 
 


     public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  
    driver.get("http://www.shop.demoqa.com");
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You have not added  selenium-server.jar in your build or dependency in your POM.

You have added selenium-java.jar in your build or as dependency due to which your code is compiling fine

You need to add that too

Download jar from below location:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server

OR add below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note that here I am using version 3.141.59 for server so your selenium java jar should of same version to prevent from any unrelated error**

Answer (score 0):

Selenium relies on [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and your test is failing to find [ImmutableMap](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java) class.

The solution is to add the relevant version of [guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) to your project [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

The full set of dependencies would be:

```
animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar
checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar
error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar
guava-25.0-jre.jar
j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
okhttp-3.11.0.jar
okio-1.14.0.jar
selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-java-3.141.59.jar
selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar
selenium-support-3.141.59.jar
```

Going forward I would recommend using a dependency management solution like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) so you won't have to manually download the .jars. Check out [Selenium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+with+Java) article for comprehensive explanation and example code snippets.